# Create a grouped bar chart with dynamic custom colors for each bar using plot_ly()

Tags: r, plotly

Im trying to create a grouped column chart with a sequential color palette like in the image below. I have assigned to each bar a color in my df. Normally this will be dynamic and the colors may differ every time but I get a stacked bar chart with no color diversity instead.

[image]

```r
Cum <- structure(list(`Age group` = c("00-04", "00-04", "05-14", "05-14", 
  "15-24", "15-24", "25-49", "25-49", "50-64", "50-64", "65-79", 
  "65-79", "80+", "80+"), Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Cases = c(64578, 70518, 
      187568, 197015, 414405, 388138, 1342394, 1206168, 792180, 742744, 
      400232, 414613, 282268, 198026), color = c("#4285f4", "#4285f4", 
        "#90a9e0", "#90a9e0", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#b45f06", "#b45f06", 
        "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#aebbd6", "#90a9e0"
      ), width = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
        "1", "1", "1", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
          -14L))      
mycols<-c("#4285f4","#6e97ea","#90a9e0","#aebbd6","#cccccc","#dd9e5f","#d58739","#c6721f","#b45f06")


fig <- plot_ly(
           data = Cum,
           x = ~ `Age group`,
           y = ~ Cases,
           type = 'bar',
           color = ~ color,
           colors = mycols,
           text=~Gender,
           textposition = 'outside',
           # rotate label
           textangle = 270,
           textfont = list(color = "black"),
           customdata = ~ paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>",`Age group` , "<br><b>Cases:</b>", Cases, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>", `Age group`),
           hovertemplate = paste('%{customdata}<extra></extra>')
         ) %>% layout(barmode = 'group',uniformtext=list(minsize=10, mode='show')
         )%>%config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
           config(displaylogo = FALSE)
         fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this work easier with `ggplot2` & `ggplot_ly`

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

mycols <- c("#4285f4", "#6e97ea", "#90a9e0", "#aebbd6", "#cccccc", "#dd9e5f",
  "#d58739", "#c6721f", "#b45f06")
names(mycols) <- mycols

ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age group`, y = Cases, group = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = color,
    # Define a text object here that can be use for reference by ggplot_ly
    # thought ggplot will throw a warning
    text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age group` ,
      "<br><b>Cases:</b>", Cases, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
      `Age group`)), 
    position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
    position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
```

```r
# running ggplotly with tooltip option reference to the text defined in ggplot object
ggplotly(ggplot_obj, tooltip="text") %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage', "zoom2d", "toggleSpikelines",
    "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "drawline", "autoScale2d",
    "resetScale2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "pan2d", 'select2d', 'lasso2d')) %>%
  config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

[image: ggplotly render]

**It is possible to do it with full `plot_ly` though I am having some challenges adjust the barwidth**

```r
plot_ly(
  data = Cum %>% group_by(`Age group`, Gender),
  x = ~`Age group`,
  y = ~Cases,
  type = "bar",
  name = ~Gender,
  color = ~color,
  colors = mycols,
  text = ~Gender,
  textposition = "outside",
  # rotate label
  textangle = 270,
  textfont = list(color = "black"),
  customdata = ~ paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", 
    `Age group`, "<br><b>Cases:</b>", Cases,
    "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>", `Age group`),
  hovertemplate = paste("%{customdata}<extra></extra>")) %>%
  layout(barmode = "group", uniformtext = list(minsize = 10, mode = "show")) %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("toImage", "zoom2d", "toggleSpikelines",
    "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "drawline", "autoScale2d",
    "resetScale2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "pan2d", "select2d", "lasso2d")) %>%
  config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why this does not work wit plot_ly(). As first choice I want a plot_ly() solution

Comment: Im going to accept your ggplotly solution if you can add the other features that I was using with plotly() like text, hovertext, axes etc. I edited my Q based on how exactly my plotly chart is being coded.

Comment: in the ggplotly solution how can I se t the textangle to 270?

Comment: I cannot do it either. can do it with ggplot but when ggplotly convert it to plotly it will become normal text

Comment: based on your abswer I did this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664095/edit-the-labels-of-the-legend-of-a-ggplot2-plot