# Edit the labels of the legend of a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the `ggplotly` chart below and I want to edit the labels of the legend from `color` to the `Range` values.

```
Cum<-data.frame(structure(list(Age.group = c("00-04", "00-04", "05-14", "05-14", 
                                             "15-24", "15-24", "25-49", "25-49", "50-64", "50-64", "65-79", 
                                             "65-79", "80+", "80+"), Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                                "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                                "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Cases = c(64578, 70518, 
                                                                                                                               187568, 197015, 414405, 388138, 1342394, 1206168, 792180, 742744, 
                                                                                                                               400232, 414613, 282268, 198026), lab = c("64,578", "70,518", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "187,568", "197,015", "414,405", "388,138", "1,342,394", "1,206,168", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "792,180", "742,744", "400,232", "414,613", "282,268", "198,026"
                                                                                                                               ), Age.group.Sum = c(135096, 135096, 384583, 384583, 802543, 
                                                                                                                                                    802543, 2548562, 2548562, 1534924, 1534924, 814845, 814845, 480294, 
                                                                                                                                                    480294), lab2 = c("135,096", "135,096", "384,583", "384,583", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "802,543", "802,543", "2,548,562", "2,548,562", "1,534,924", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "1,534,924", "814,845", "814,845", "480,294", "480,294"), color = c("#4285f4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "#4285f4", "#90a9e0", "#90a9e0", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#b45f06", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#aebbd6", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "#90a9e0"), Range = c("<= 74453.8555555556", "<= 74453.8555555556", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "148907.711111111 - 223361.566666667", "148907.711111111 - 223361.566666667", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "372269.277777778 - 446723.133333333", "372269.277777778 - 446723.133333333", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ">= 670084.7", ">= 670084.7", ">= 670084.7", ">= 670084.7", "372269.277777778 - 446723.133333333", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "372269.277777778 - 446723.133333333", "223361.566666667 - 297815.422222222", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "148907.711111111 - 223361.566666667")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -14L)))


      
      ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age group`, y = Cases, group = Gender,fill = Range)) +
        geom_bar(aes(
          # Define a text object here that can be use for reference by ggplot_ly
          # thought ggplot will throw a warning
          text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age group` ,
                       "<br><b>Cases:</b>", lab, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
                       lab2)), 
          position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
        geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
                  position = position_dodge(width=0.9),size=2) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
        theme_bw()+ theme(
          # remove the vertical grid lines
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line()
        )+
        scale_y_continuous(labels = paste0(ylab, "M"),
                           breaks = 10^6 * ylab)
      #> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
      # running ggplotly with tooltip option reference to the text defined in ggplot object
      ggplotly(ggplot_obj, tooltip="text") %>%
        config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage', "zoom2d", "toggleSpikelines",
                                          "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "drawline", "autoScale2d",
                                          "resetScale2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "pan2d", 'select2d', 'lasso2d')) %>%
        config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fill = Range` is what you need to do:

```
ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age group`, y = Cases, group = Gender, fill = Range)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
                 text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age group` ,
                              "<br><b>Cases:</b>", Cases, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
                              `Age group`)) +
        geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
                  position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
        theme_bw()
ggplotly(ggplot_obj, tooltip="text") %>%
        config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage', "zoom2d", "toggleSpikelines",
                                          "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "drawline", "autoScale2d",
                                          "resetScale2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "pan2d", 'select2d', 'lasso2d')) %>%
        config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

[image]

Note: I removed `fill = color` from the `geom_bar` `aes` as it does not make sense to have both `mycols` and `color` at the same time.

Comment: I have tried to use it in my df and I get white columns I have edit with my df structure